# How can access a object in main class from another class in java?

Tags: java

I have a main class and two sub class in java language.how can access xx in class Y?please help me ,I need it in my project.

```
import class X,Y;
public static void main(String[] args) {
xx=new X;
example=new Y;
}
public class Y{
change xx.value;//how can change it?
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? can you give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you can do it with an accessor and [mutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) (or getter and setter if you prefer) and something like,

```
static class X {
    public X(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    int value;
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}

static class Y {
    public void example(X x) {
        System.out.println("in example");
        x.setValue(x.getValue() + 5);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    X xx = new X(10);
    System.out.printf("xx = %s%n", xx);
    Y yy = new Y();
    yy.example(xx);
    System.out.printf("xx = %s%n", xx);
}
```

Output is

```
xx = 10
in example
xx = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

make xx become parameter of method of class Y, because JAVA use reference by default (for object), so that if you change xx in method of class Y, it also apply to method main

```
import class X,Y;
public static void main(String[] args) {
 xx=new X;
 example=new Y;
 example.modify(xx)
}
public class Y{
 public void modify(X xx){ //change xx here)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside Y class with a type X parameter, then you can call this function from your Main class and change xx value.

```
   import class X,Y;
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   xx=new X;
   example=new Y;
   xx=example.changeXValue(xx);
    }
   public class Y{

   public X changeXValue(X xx){
   //change xx here
   return xx;
   }
   }
```